# Верстка под различные экраны iPhone SpriteKit

Tags: ios, разработка-игр, swift, cocoa

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно позиционировать элементы на сцене/экране, что бы они находились в одном и том же месте(относительно других элементов) на разных моделях айфона. 
Сейчас делаю так:

```
 water.position = CGPoint (x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 76 * xScaleFactor
        , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 35 * yScaleFactor)
```

ScaleFactor фактор считаю так

```
xScaleFactor = self.size.width / 320.0
```

в iPhone 5/5s все хорошо. 
Но для шестерок уезжает, и встает не туда куда нужно. Вот скриншоты:

Для iPhone 5s

[image: Для iPhone 5s]

А вот для iPhone 6s Plus

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Comment: предположу, что позиции у вас правильные, а вот размер нет - для iPhone6 вам надо и размер элементов увеличивать на тот же scaleFactor.

Comment: Ваш совет помог. увеличил картинку на scale и она встала куда нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: перенес в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что позиции у вас правильные, а вот размер нет - для iPhone6 вам надо и размер элементов увеличивать на тот же scaleFactor.